# Correct place to load data in connected redux component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Where is the correct place to load data in a redux component?

Currently I have it this way.

Say I have this container component:

```
import { loadResultsPage } from '../actions/winratio-actions';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {
    isFetching,
    results
  } = state;

  return {
    isFetching,
    results
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  loadResultsPage
})(WinRatio);
```

I then make a call in the wrapped component's `componentWillMount` lifecycle event:

```
export default class WinRatio extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.loadResultsPage();
  }

  render()  {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Win Ratio</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Where should this call happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your container component. If you use redux you probably use smart\dumb components strategy. Create a container where you use `compose` function from redux package and you can compose it like this:

```
export default compose(
  connect(null, { loadData }), //this is your async action
  doOnComponentMount(({props}) => props.loadData()),
)(MyDumbComponent)
```

and doOnComponentMount is:

```
function doOnComponentMount(cb) {
  return (Component) => {
    return class extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        cb(this);
      }

      render() {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }
    }
  }
}
```